# Bootstrap 4.00 columns aren't breaking to new line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

Not really sure what's going on. As I decrease the width of the browser, the columns are supposed to go to the next line, but instead, they're going over top of each other, why?

Does it have to do with the way I'm naming the column classes? There's three so I put col-4 for each of them. Why don't they go to the next line when the width of the browser gets smaller?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Test
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Test
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Test
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input class="btn-light" type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Test
          </label>   
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <span class="main">Date</label>
          <input id="dashboardDatePick" type="date" name="date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <span class="main">Date 2</label>
          <input id="dashboardTimePick" type="date" name="time">
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: row inside container ...

Comment: also remove the integrity if you are using the file locally, it may create issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif it does not help to solve problem his real problem is `col-4` see my answer

Comment: @לבנימלכה I never said this will solve the problem ;) ... I was correcting other things because in bootstrap we need to use row inside container whatever the situation is.

Comment: Was not aware rows had to be inside a container. Thank you.

Comment: @AranBins: Check you code there some issue in it.... I have found `<span class="main">Date 2</label>` in which you are using `<span>` but there is no closing tag for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's built in class to be used here should be:

```
.col-md-4
```

and not

```
.col-4
```

Please change all occurrences of .col-4 to .col-md-4 to get your desired result.

Edit: This will set medium screen sizes as a break point below which the div will occupy 100% of the width of the screen, hence the three divs will be stacked one below each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to break line you have to define from what size of screen they take other `width`

You set `col-4` what means that **all** sizes of screen it sets `col-4`(`width:33.33%`)

As you said you want them to brake line that the reason **you need to declare size;**

for example:

```
col-md-4
```

→ from md and up it sets `width:33.33%` (`12/4=3 => 100%:3=33.33%`) and down from md (means `sm` and `xs`) it sets `width:100%`

Learn more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input class="btn-light" type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>   
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="main">Date</label>
                <input id="dashboardDatePick" type="date" name="date">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span class="main">Date 2</label>
                <input id="dashboardTimePick" type="date" name="time">
            </div>                          

    </div>
 </div>
```

**Note!**

> bootstrap 4 removed `xs` size whats mean `col-*` is from `xs` and up

Comment: Isn't col-md-4 33%? Also I thought bootstrap 4 removed xs, sm, md, lg, etc.?

Comment: you right i  edited... they remove just `xs` instead they set `col-*`

Comment: @AranBins the V4 removed only the xs and made some changes to the other as it's now mobile first https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: I added this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

In latest Bootstrap 4 version, col-4 stands the width is 33.33% for all device. Instead of using col-4 you can use col-lg-4 or col-md-4 for getting your desire result in responsive design.

```html
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type='text/css'>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>
                  <label class="btn btn-primary">
                    <input class="btn-light" type="radio" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Test
                  </label>   
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <span class="main">Date</label>
                <input id="dashboardDatePick" type="date" name="date">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <span class="main">Date 2</label>
                <input id="dashboardTimePick" type="date" name="time">
            </div>                          

    </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```